# Unable to get alert within time and location range in android

Tags: android, alert, location-based-service

I am new to android and I am developing my 1st application for location based reminder where I am adding tasks with locations and date and time for which when I reach I should be notified. I have a switch button for location if set on whenever i reach the location i should be notified and if set off alert will be on location and date and time. I can either give only location for the alert or Location and date and time for the alert.

Layout :-

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/relative1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bckgrnd_4">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Task Name"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/taskname"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/taskname"
    android:hint="@string/hint_name"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
    >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:onClick="set_loc"
    style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/switch1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Set Location"

    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/taskname" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Always alert me"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/relative3" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relative2"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pickDate"
        android:src="@drawable/cal"
        style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
        android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pickTime"
        style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
        android:src="@drawable/alert"
        android:layout_marginStart="67dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pickDate"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/pickDate" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relative3"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Add Task"
        android:onClick="add_task"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/add"
        style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
         />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:onClick="cancel"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bck"
        style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginStart="37dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Activity :-

```
public class AddTasks extends Activity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

TaskForm activityForm = new TaskForm();

private ImageButton pPickDate;
private int pYear;
private int pMonth;
private int pDay;
public String date;
public String Loc;
public double lat;
public double lon;

private ImageButton pPickTime;
private int mHour;
private int mMinute;
public String time;

private TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;

Date selectedDate;


/** This integer will uniquely define the dialog to be used for displaying date picker.*/
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1;

/** Callback received when the user "picks" a date in the dialog */
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                pYear = year;
                pMonth = monthOfYear;
                pDay = dayOfMonth;
               updateDate();
                displayDateToast();
            }
        };

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeListener =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
                mHour = hour;
                mMinute = minute;
                updateTime();
                displayTimeToast();
            }
        };

/** Updates the date in the TextView */
private void updateDate() {
  /**  pDisplayDate.setText( */ date =
            new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(pDay).append("/")
                    .append(pMonth + 1).append("/")
                    .append(pYear).append(" ").toString();
   // date = pDisplayDate.getText().toString();

}

private void updateTime() {
   /** pDisplayTime.setText( */ time =
            new StringBuilder()
                    .append(mHour).append(":")
                    .append(mMinute).append("").toString();
}

/** Displays a notification when the date is updated */
private void displayDateToast() {
    //Toast.makeText(this, new StringBuilder().append("Date choosen is ").append(date),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    activityForm.setTaskDateInput(date);
}

private void displayTimeToast() {
  //  Toast.makeText(this, new StringBuilder().append("Time choosen is ").append(time),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    activityForm.setTaskTimeInput(time);
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout2 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative2);
    if(isChecked) {
        relativeLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        relativeLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addtask);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Switch aSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative1);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout3 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative3);

    aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    init();

    /** Capture our View elements */
    //pDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayDate);
    pPickDate = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);

    /** Listener for click event of the button */
    pPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

   /** Capture our View elements */
    //pDisplayTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayTime);
    pPickTime = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pickTime);


    /** Listener for click event of the button */
    pPickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    /** Get the current date and time */
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    pYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    pMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     pDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    mHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
}

/** Create a new dialog for date and time picker */
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            datePickerDialog =  new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    pDateSetListener,
                    pYear, pMonth, pDay);
            Date dt = new Date();
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(dt);
            mHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
           mMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(dt.getTime() - 10000);
           // datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime() - 10000);
            return datePickerDialog;

        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    mTimeListener,
                    mHour,mMinute,true) ;
             return timePickerDialog;


    }
    return null;
}


public void set_loc(View v)
{
Intent i = new Intent(this, Set_Location.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 2);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 2) {
        try {

            lat = data.getDoubleExtra("lat", 0.0);
            lon = data.getDoubleExtra("lon", 0.0);
            String loc_name = data.getStringExtra("loc");

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "loc " + lat + ":" + lon,
            //      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //   Loc = String.valueOf(lat) + String.valueOf(lon);
            Loc = loc_name;
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Loc : " + loc_name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            activityForm.setTaskLocInput(Loc);
            activityForm.setTaskLat(lat);
            activityForm.setTaskLon(lon);
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e("Null", "Null");

        }
    }
}

private void persistTask(Task task) {

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;

    try {
        fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("" + task.hashCode(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
                fileOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(task);
        objectOutputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("file out", "file out");
    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
}

public void add_task(View view) {

    if(activityForm.getTaskNameInput().getText() != null  ) {
        if (activityForm.getTaskLocInput() != null
                && activityForm.getTaskLat() != null && activityForm.getTaskLon() != null)
        {

            Task task = new Task();
            task.setTaskNameString(activityForm.getTaskNameInput().getText()
                    .toString());
            task.setTaskLocString(activityForm.getTaskLocInput());
            task.setTaskLat(activityForm.getTaskLat());
            task.setTaskLon(activityForm.getTaskLon());
            task.setDateString(activityForm.getTaskDateInput());
            task.setTimeString(activityForm.getTaskTimeInput());

            persistTask(task);

            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SAVED=" + task.hashCode(),
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            activityForm.getTaskNameInput().setText(" ");

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            if (timePickerDialog != null) {
                timePickerDialog.updateTime(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            }

            if (datePickerDialog != null) {
                datePickerDialog.updateDate(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            }
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.setTitle("Attention");
            dialog.setMessage("Please select Location");
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
    else {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Attention");
        dialog.setMessage("Please enter task name");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            }
        });
        dialog.show();

    }
}

private void init() {

    activityForm
            .setTaskNameInput((EditText) findViewById(R.id.taskname));

}
```

Service :-

```
public class LocService extends Service {

LocationManager lm ;

Location location ;

// default 0.0
double lat;
double lon;
String name, loca;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service wokeup",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(MainActivity.context != null) {
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }

    if(location != null)
    {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
        Log.i("",""+ lat + " | " + lon);
    }

    processTasks();

    location = null;
    lat = 0.0;
    lon = 0.0;

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private void processTasks() {

    List<Task> tasks = loadFiles();

    if(tasks == null || tasks.size() < 1){
     //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Tasks Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    for (Task task : tasks) {

        if (tasks != null && task.alert) {
            Log.i("Task is ",task.toString());
           //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Task is " + task.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // if in time range
            boolean timeRange = true;

            // if in loc range
            boolean locRange = true;
            if(task.getTaskLocString() != null && task.getTaskLat() !=null && task.getTaskLon()!= null) {
                float dst = 0.0f;
                if (lat > 0.0 && lon > 0.0) {
                    float[] results = new float[1];
                    Location.distanceBetween(lat, lon, task.getTaskLat(), task.getTaskLon(), results);
                    float distanceInMeters = results[0];
                    dst = distanceInMeters;
                    Log.i("dist", "" + distanceInMeters);
                    boolean isWithin5km = distanceInMeters < 5000;
                    locRange = isWithin5km;
                }
                Log.i("bool", "" + locRange);
                //  Toast.makeText(this,"dist is " + dst ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if (dst < 5000) {
                    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Booooom",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    locRange = true;
                } else {
                    locRange = false;
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Faaalse",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

          //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Date is " + task.getDateString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if(task.getDateString() != null && task.getTimeString() != null) {
                // format date
                String datearr[] = task.getDateString().split("/");
                int day = Integer.parseInt(datearr[0]);
                int month = Integer.parseInt(datearr[1]);
                month--;
                int year = Integer.parseInt(datearr[2].trim());

                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Date is " + datearr,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Time is " + task.getTimeString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //format time
                String timearr[] = task.getTimeString().split(":");

                if (timearr != null) {
                    Log.i("=>", timearr.toString());
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Time is " + timearr.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Log.e("tme null", "time null");
                    //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Time is Null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                int hour = Integer.parseInt(timearr[0]);
                int minute = Integer.parseInt(timearr[1]);

                // month range 0-11
                Calendar event = Calendar.getInstance();
                event.set(year, month, day, hour, minute);

                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

                Log.i("event", "" + event.toString());
                Log.i("now", "" + now.toString());

                int hourNow = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int dNow = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int mNow = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int yNow = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int minNow = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                Log.i("year", "" + yNow + " y " + year);
                Log.i("mnth", "" + mNow + " m " + month);
                Log.i("day", "" + dNow + " d " + day);
                Log.i("minute", "" + minNow + "min" + minute);

                if (yNow == year && mNow == month && dNow == day) {
                    if (hourNow == hour && minNow == minute) {
                        timeRange = true;
                    } else {
                        Log.i("hour", "" + (hour - hourNow));
                    }
                }
            }

           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Values are :- " + day + " , " + month + " , " + year + " , " + hour + " , " + minute,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // timeRange = true;
           // Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Time Range is " + timeRange,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Loc Range is " + locRange,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            name = task.getTaskNameString();
            loca = task.getTaskLocString();

             if (timeRange && locRange) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Task is " + task.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               // Alertview.TASK_STATIC = task;
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String L = gson.toJson(loca);
                String N = gson.toJson(name);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Alertview.class);
                intent.putExtra("Loc", L);
                intent.putExtra("name",N);
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        getApplicationContext());
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                builder.setContentTitle("Alert !!!!");
                builder.setContentText(" " + name);
                builder.setLights(Color.WHITE, 1500, 1500);
                builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
                builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
                builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
                builder.setDefaults(Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS);
                builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
                builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                manager.notify(99, builder.build());
                task.alert = false;
                persistTask(task);

            }


        }
    }
}

private void persistTask(Task task) {

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;

    try {
        fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("" + task.hashCode(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
                fileOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(task);
        objectOutputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("file out", "file out");
    }

}

private List<Task> loadFiles() {
    List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();

    File file = getFilesDir();
    File[] files = file.listFiles();

    for (File temp : files) {
        try {
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(temp));
            Task task = (Task) is.readObject();
            is.close();

            tasks.add(task);
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            Log.e("file read", "file read");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("file read", "file read");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("file read", "file read");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("file read", "file read");
        }
    }

    return tasks;
}
```

}

In the above service first m checking if task's location is not null set locRange to true and if date time is not null timeRange to true i.e here :-

```
boolean timeRange = true;

            // if in loc range
            boolean locRange = true;
            if(task.getTaskLocString() != null && task.getTaskLat() !=null && task.getTaskLon()!= null) {
                float dst = 0.0f;
                if (lat > 0.0 && lon > 0.0) {
                    float[] results = new float[1];
                    Location.distanceBetween(lat, lon, task.getTaskLat(), task.getTaskLon(), results);
                    float distanceInMeters = results[0];
                    dst = distanceInMeters;
                    Log.i("dist", "" + distanceInMeters);
                    boolean isWithin5km = distanceInMeters < 5000;
                    locRange = isWithin5km;
                }
                Log.i("bool", "" + locRange);
                //  Toast.makeText(this,"dist is " + dst ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if (dst < 5000) {
                    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Booooom",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    locRange = true;
                } else {
                    locRange = false;
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Faaalse",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

          //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Date is " + task.getDateString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if(task.getDateString() != null && task.getTimeString() != null) {
                // format date
                String datearr[] = task.getDateString().split("/");
                int day = Integer.parseInt(datearr[0]);
                int month = Integer.parseInt(datearr[1]);
                month--;
                int year = Integer.parseInt(datearr[2].trim());

                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Date is " + datearr,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Time is " + task.getTimeString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //format time
                String timearr[] = task.getTimeString().split(":");

                if (timearr != null) {
                    Log.i("=>", timearr.toString());
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Time is " + timearr.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Log.e("tme null", "time null");
                    //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Time is Null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                int hour = Integer.parseInt(timearr[0]);
                int minute = Integer.parseInt(timearr[1]);

                // month range 0-11
                Calendar event = Calendar.getInstance();
                event.set(year, month, day, hour, minute);

                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

                Log.i("event", "" + event.toString());
                Log.i("now", "" + now.toString());

                int hourNow = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int dNow = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int mNow = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int yNow = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int minNow = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                Log.i("year", "" + yNow + " y " + year);
                Log.i("mnth", "" + mNow + " m " + month);
                Log.i("day", "" + dNow + " d " + day);
                Log.i("minute", "" + minNow + "min" + minute);

                if (yNow == year && mNow == month && dNow == day) {
                    if (hourNow == hour && minNow == minute) {
                        timeRange = true;
                    } else {
                        Log.i("hour", "" + (hour - hourNow));
                    }
                }
            }
```

After doing the above if for say i add 3 tasks :-

- Task1 :- Location >5km and NO date time (for this m not getting the alert which is right)
- Task2 :- Location<5km and NO date time (m getting the alert which is also right)
- Task3 :- Loaction<5km, date - 31/5/2015 and time - 11:12 (for this task it is not checking the timerange condition i.e the minute i add the task say at 11:05 m getting the alert)

What am i missing ? Please help me this is the main part of my application..

Comment: Does displayTimeToast() display the time you had selected using the dialog?

Comment: i have commented it.. just a sec i'll remove the comment and check..

Comment: Yes, If i add date and time m able to get the toast..

Comment: While processing the tasks in the service, Log and check if you get the same date and time you had selected back in your activity.

Comment: @siris_cac yes m able to get the values from service which i entered..

Comment: i have two boolean values timeRange and locRange.. what does this mean if(timeRange && locRange) ? if both the values are false will this satisfy ? or this applies to only if they are true ?

Comment: If either of the values are false, the if condition is not satisfied (or) the if condition is satisfied only if both timeRange and locRange is true.

Comment: I tried testing by giving different situations but if i have both the values false then too m getting the alert.. this should not happen in this case..

Comment: Like for eg :- Location >5km and future date and time this means both are false for the alert then too m getting the alert.. either m not setting the boolean values properly or the if case has some problem... please help me..

Comment: Hi did you fixed this problem. I am also implenting location and time based notifier. Currently i have implemented geofence only for location notifier.